# problem while trying to run a joomla website on my localhost

Tags: joomla

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'JClassLoader' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla\libraries\cms.php:38 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla\includes\framework.php(20): require_once() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla\index.php(40): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla\libraries\cms.php on line 38

The line 38:
spl_autoload_register(array(new JClassLoader($loader), 'loadClass'), true, true);

I tried searching and i found this info on joomla website but i don't know what to do

JClassLoader
Decorate Composer ClassLoader for Joomla!
For backward compatibility due to class aliasing in the CMS, the loadClass() method was modified to call the JLoader::applyAliasFor() method.

Comment: Please post ypur Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.